# GWT Cell Browser Selection

Tags: gwt, user-interface, widget

Does anybody know how to attach a selection model to a cell browser so that I can get the object being selected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example of [GWT showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellBrowser):

Create your selection model:

```
final MultiSelectionModel<YourKeyProvider> selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<YourKeyProvider>(fKeyProvider);
```

Add it to the browser:

```
CellBrowser cellBrowser = new CellBrowser(new ContactTreeViewModel(selectionModel), null);
```

Use [`getSelectedSet()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/view/client/MultiSelectionModel.html#getSelectedSet%28%29) to retrieve the current selected items.